# openlayers get attribute from wms

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I am serving up a wms layer from Geoserver in OpenLayers and am trying to extract a specific attribute from an object in this layer when I click on the map.

I am defining my wms layer like this:

```
oas = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"oas",
"http://www.bwgeoserver.com/geoserver/UK_Admin/wms",
    {
      "LAYERS": 'wealthmap_bdy',
      transparent: 'true',
      extractAttributes: 'true'
    },
    {
      buffer: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
      isBaseLayer: false
    }
    );
map.addLayer(oas);
```

The layer is displaying OK on the map. I am using a proxy server and there isn't a cross-domain problem as I can select and display all of the attributes in a popup.
"OA11Code" is definitely a field on the wms layer, and it displays ok with the other attributes in the popup.

But when I try to extract this attribute from the selected object using this code:

```
oaPicker = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
             url: 'http://www.bwgeoserver.com/geoserver/UK_Admin/wms',
             title: 'identify features on click',
             layers: [oas],
             queryVisible: true
         });

oaPicker.events.register('getfeatureinfo', this, selectid);
map.addControl(oaPicker);
oaPicker.activate();

function selectid(e) {
    var val = e.features[0].attributes.OA11Code;
}
```

I get an error in the Firefox debugger saying:

> "TypeError: e.features[0] is undefined".

All I want is to be able to click on the map, extract the value of an attribute from the wms layer, assign it to a javascript variable and do something with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you test the value of `e` in your `selectid(e)` function?   Can to use browser debuggers to intercept the `getfeatureinfo` request to your geoserver and the response?  Geoservers logs could provide some insight as well if these aren't conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

By default GeoServer will return plain text for a GetFeaureinfo request but parsing that can be a bit of a lottery (especially if any of the features could be null or contain special characters).

A better solution is to set the `info_format` parameter to `application/json` so that you get a JSON response like [this](http://www.bwgeoserver.com/geoserver/UK_Admin/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&BBOX=482520.350151%2C233129.91117%2C502987.165224%2C271097.336233&SERVICE=WMS&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&QUERY_LAYERS=UK_Admin%3Awealthmap_bdy&FEATURE_COUNT=50&Layers=UK_Admin%3Awealthmap_bdy&WIDTH=276&HEIGHT=512&format=image%2Fpng&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A27700&version=1.1.1&x=181&y=439) that is easy to parse.

Comment: Thank you for the responses to this question. It seems that the problem was indeed due to the format of the object being returned. I changed the format using the line:     oaPicker.infoFormat = 'application/vnd.ogc.gml'. This did the trick.